# docker-compose command python script does not execute

Tags: python, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, pgadmin-4

I have a docker-compose.yml file where I am trying to build two services postgres and pgadmin. Basically I am following [this](https://technology.amis.nl/continuous-delivery/provisioning/pgadmin-in-docker-provision-connections-and-passwords/) article where pgAdmin container Provisioning connections and passwords manually using `docker exec` command. But I was trying to load the server connections automatically using `command:` in docker-compose.yml file. Here is my docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: '3.5'

services:
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres_container
    image: postgres:12.1
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER:-postgres}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD:-Welcome01}
      PGDATA: /data/postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres:/data/postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - postgres
    restart: unless-stopped

  pgadmin:
    container_name: pgadmin_container
    image: dpage/pgadmin4:4.16
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL:-pgadmin4@pgadmin.org}
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD:-admin}
      PYTHONPATH: '$${PYTHONPATH}:/pgadmin4'
    volumes:
      - pgadmin:/root/.pgadmin
      - ./db/conn/server.json:/tmp/server.json
      - ./db/conn/pgpassfile:/tmp/pgpassfile
    ports:
      - "${PGADMIN_PORT:-5050}:80"
    networks:
      - postgres
    restart: unless-stopped
    command: sh -c "python /pgadmin4/setup.py --load-servers /tmp/server.json"

networks:
  postgres:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  postgres:
  pgadmin:
```

After executing `docker-compose up -d` all the commands executed successfully except follwing:-

```
command: sh -c "python /pgadmin4/setup.py --load-servers /tmp/server.json"
```

I can access the **pgdadmin_container** and can browse the web interface as well. Even the following command also works.

```
docker exec -it pgadmin_container python /pgadmin4/setup.py --load-servers /tmp/server.json
Added 0 Server Group(s) and 1 Server(s).
```

However, that `command:` does not work. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: When you say "it doesn't work", what happens?  Remember that a Compose `command:` runs _instead of_ the normal container command, so I might expect that setup script to run _instead of_ running the PGAdmin server.

Comment: So, can you suggest a solution specifically?